# min(lag) over partition with conditions

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a table such as

```
event_id | user_id | date | event_type_A | event_type_B
  uuid       uuid    date      bool            bool
```

an event is either type A or type B. 
each user may have 1 up to N events. 

I want to obtain a table of events that were **type A** that looks like this:

```
event_id | user_id | date | min(delta)
```

Where min(delta) is the minimum lag or lead between that event and any event **type_B** from the same user_id.

How should I proceed?

I would imagine I should use a partition over command, but its unclear how to include both conditions (to compare B's over A's)

*note: dataset is rather large so efficiency is relevant.*

*edit:

input example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=46a086629727e597ec0fe0ac7f37c1b7

output example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=9776d3f0e83cd1a59709b7ad67257e22

note: its also possible to have a single column with event type (a or b) if that makes the solution easier

Comment: Could you create a filddle with some examples? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

friend of mine sent me a valid solution;

something in the lines of

```
with base as (select *
               , lag(case when event_type_b = true then event_date end)
                 ignore nulls over (partition by user_id order by event_date asc) as date_lag
               , lead(case when event_type_b = true then event_date end)
                 ignore nulls over (partition by user_id order by event_date asc) as date_lead
               , abs(datediff(days, event_date, date_lag))                        as diff_lag
               , abs(datediff(days, event_date, date_lead))                       as diff_lead
          from #big_table)
select event_id, user_id, event_date, min(coalesce(diff_lag,diff_lead))
from base group by 1,2,3;
```